# what is Fixed address variable in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, embedded

I have seen many examples of this in books and Embedded system related sites..
As per my understanding , Its for accessing a data that is stored in that fixed memory address .
Here is the example i got in some book;

```
unsigned char *p=(unsigned char *)0x41E;
```

What is the use of the type cast `(unsigned char *)` , there we could have used directly like

```
unsigned char *p=0x41E;
```

Please explain in detail, What's the use of type cast there, and are we storing the address `0x41E` itself to the pointer `p` or something else is stored in that?

I am totally confused.
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the use of the type cast.. (unsigned char *) , there we could have used directly like `unsigned char *p=0x41E`

`0x41E` is a hexadecimal number and it doesn't mean that it is of type `unsigned char *`. You should have to tell the compiler, by casting it to `unsigned char *`, that it is an address (of type `unsigned char *`).

> are we storing the address "0x41E" itself to the pointer p, or something else is stored in that.

Yes, we storing the address `0x41E` to the pointer `p`. By doing `unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)0x41E`, you are informing the compiler that `p` is pointing to the memory location `0x41E` and by dereferencing `p` it will get the content stored at memory location `0x41E`.
Just check it out by running this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned char *p=(unsigned char *)0x41E;
    printf("%p\n",p);
}
```

Output:

```
0000041E  //output is not 0x41E because '0x' is used as prefix to inform the compiler that it is a hexadecimal number
```

Answer (score 5):

The value `0x41e` is not a pointer, so the compiler would have complained about it. That's why it has to be type-casted as a pointer type.

And pointers are normal variables whose contents (value) is the address the pointer points to. It's treated specially by the compiler, to access what the pointer points to when dereferencing the pointer.

As for "fixed address variable", many embedded platforms have data and/or registers at special fixed addresses. To access this data or these registers, you often use pointers that are initialized to those addresses.

Answer (score 5):

The cast is mainly to keep the compiler happy, but there may be certain architectures where a pointer address has to be converted to some format other than just the plain bits of a number. In segmented architectures, for example, there might be an actual conversion involved in the cast. As far the final result, though, `(char *)0x41E` just means "interpret the number 0x41E as a pointer address", a dereferencing it grabs the char at that address.

Comment: actually, it is wrong: you should do unsigned char *p; <new line>  "p = address"

Comment: @grazianogovernatori: What do you assert is wrong, and why is it wrong?

Comment: @Lee "The cast is mainly to keep the compiler happy": this is not correct, it is an error to assign an unsigned char an integer (*p is actually a char...)

Comment: @grazianogovernator It's not the destination which is being modified, but the address.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that, in many compilers for embedded world, you have ways to specify a specific address, (e.g. IAR compiler)

```
const unsigned char test_var @0x41E = 'a';
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is not helpful, as it is based on your misunderstanding of the intent of the code in question.

Comment: "Hope this helps" -definitivly not! This is even incorrect syntax. And absolutly wrong what you are saying!

Comment: Corrected: I removed first part of my answer (erroneous, from my side).

Comment: about syntax: it is not ansi C, but, since we're talking about embedded, I reported a possibility you have in embedded compilers.

Comment: There is really never a reason to use non-standard syntax for this, on any embedded system. The reason embedded compilers provide such a non-standard method, is because it enables the possibility to view hardware registers as variables, in the case of a poorly designed debugger. There is no other reason for it, as far as I know. A better solution is to use 100% standard C and then use a good debugger instead of a poor one.

Comment: actually, a reason could be assigning a group of variables to a range, in memory (instead of assigning to a specific address), for example, for normative redundancy.  but this is slightly more complex than my example.  Same syntax is used to assign variables to a segment.

Answer (score 0):

`char` type is a type of portability in C.
As each memory area is allowed to get aliased by a `char *` since c99.
So if you don't know what type will be expected, or you even had to use different types, you are on the safe side if you use the type of `char *` to alias the types.

And if you use some fixed addresses, You are probably working on a lower level machine where `char` type is best to work with as the standard gives for `char` that it shall be 1 Byte.

Comment: OP didn't ask about `char` type.

Comment: Nope but he asked for explanation, and thats what I gave. But nvm. If thats enough for downvoting in our eyes...